# inheriting (a legacy of) cultural achievements

Tags: word-choice, collocations

In this period, the indigenous Vietnamese culture developed while **inheriting a legacy of cultural achievements from the previous period**. The representative achievements of this period were Dong Son bronze drum and wet rice cultivation.

Is the bolded phrase a bit too lengthy and unnecessary?

I intended to write: In this period, the indigenous Vietnamese culture developed while **inheriting the cultural achievements from the previous period**. The representative achievements of this period were Dong Son bronze drum and wet rice cultivation

However, I found that "legacy" and "inherit" are collocations. Therefore, adding it makes the sentence sound more natural. What should I use here?

Comment: Can you explain how this is a question about learning English and not about writing style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have written is fine, but if you wanted to shorten it you could consider leaving out **from the previous period** as this is implied by **inheriting a legacy**. You can't inherit a legacy from the present or the future.
Based on your comment to the first version of my answer, the two sentences could be further simplified, without loss of meaning by saying

> In period A, the indigenous Vietnamese culture developed things such as  the Dong Son bronze drum and wet rice cultivation whilst
> inheriting a legacy of cultural achievements of the previous period B

Comment: Oh sorry but what I meant was: In this period (Period A), the indigenous Vietnamese culture developed while inheriting a legacy of cultural achievements from the previous period(Period B). The representative achievements of this period (Period A) were Dong Son bronze drum and wet rice cultivation.

Comment: @HaiDuong No problem. Reading your post again I see that, unfortunately, it is ambiguous.  "The representative achievements of this period" can be read as applying to either period A or B. I will try to edit my answer to correct this misunderstanding.

Comment: Thank you for your help so much. Your edit is really useful

Comment: @HaiDuong Would you please mind marking it as useful then?

Comment: Oh sorry I'm new to this. Just did